# API Google Calendar, Hangout is not created

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

We have a PHP application and when we create an event in Google Calendar using de API, this event is generated without Hangout Link, but if we create the event manually, the event is created with the Hangout Link. The option to create automatically hangouts when we create an event is checked.

The code is:

```
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setSummary($summary);
    $event->setLocation('hangout');
    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($startDate->format(\DateTime::ISO8601));
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($endDate->format(\DateTime::ISO8601));
    $event->setEnd($end);


    $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail($this->masterAccount);


    $attendees= [];
    $attendees[] = $attendee1;

    foreach($company->getUsers()->toArray() as $user){
        $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
        $attendee1->setEmail($user->getEmail());
        $attendees[] = $attendee1;
    }
    $event->attendees = $attendees;
    $createdEvent = $this->google_calendar_service->events->insert($company->getCalendar()->getCalendarId(), $event);
```

If we use the form https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it to create de Event, the hangout link is created without problems.

Any solutions?
Thanks :)

Comment: anybody can help me? :(

Comment: check this link http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2012/11/programmatically-scheduling-hangouts.html Did you checked "automatically add Google+ hangouts" button in the settings,(go to calendar settings->general->"automatically add Google+ hangouts" button)

Comment: @user3396420: Have you acheived this? I am also facing the same problem. Can you please guide me on this

Comment: Ditto, did you find an answer for your question?

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is a bit old, but there are many people still struggling with making Calendar API work. After countless forums visited, hours of reading documentation and hitting my head against the wall I finally figured out, the key element is to set `requestId`.

In the time i've implemented this, this parameter wasn't mandatory and i skipped it.

Thats being said, my request looks like this:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(); //creating empty event
$event->setSummary("Staff meeting"); //title
$event->setLocation("Room 101"); //location
$event->setDescription("We will talk about salary raise!"); //description
$event->setColorId(9); //make it shine by setting color

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($startDate->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
$start->setTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$event->setStart($start); //set start

$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($endDate->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
$end->setTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$event->setEnd($end); //set end

$event->setGuestsCanSeeOtherGuests(false); //I dont want others to see who's invited
$event->setGuestsCanModify(false); //I dont want others to modify event
$event->setGuestsCanInviteOthers(false); //I dont want others to invite
$event->setAnyoneCanAddSelf(false); //I allow only people invited by me, not some strangers walking by

//this part should be executed in loop, for every guest
$attendee = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee->setEmail("staffmeber1@mywebsite.com");
$attendee->setResponseStatus('accepted');
$attendees[] = $attendee;

//When the list is completed, set guests in event
$event->setAttendees($attendees);

//The most important part about creating hangout
$conferenceData = new Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData(); //defining we have conference
$req = new Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest(); //requesting google to create video meeting
$req->setRequestId("req_".time()); //some random string/number changed every call. according to docs subsequent calls with the same request id are ignored
$conferenceData->setCreateRequest($req); //set request for videoconference in conference data
$event->setConferenceData($conferenceData); //set conference data in out event

$creator = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator();
$creator->setDisplayName("Big boss");
$creator->setEmail('boss@mywebsite.com');
$event->setCreator($creator);

$event->setStatus('confirmed'); //lets say everyone is attending :D


$result = $this->calendarClient->events->insert($this->calendarObject->getId(), $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1, 'sendUpdates' => "none"]); //dont forget about conferenceDataVersion or every conference data will be ignored
```

Answer (score -1):

Working with Python here also faced issue, of events not being created with Hangouts. It seems settings can not be changed from program, but as SGC [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372031/api-google-calendar-hangout-is-not-created#comment49008422_30372031), I just changed google calendar settings from UI to add hangouts on every event created.

[image]